# Sdk Manager not opening from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

SDK Manager is not opening from eclipse. An initialization screen comes but the SDK Manager doesn't open. I have tried renaming android.bat file but that doesnt work. Re-installing has also been tried.

Comment: try open from ~/Android/android-sdk/SDK_Manager.exe. If reinstalled SDK - make sure that the folder '.android' has been deleted.

Comment: use Android Studio =))

Comment: @agamov - I had all kinds of problems with Android Studio.

Comment: @agamov: and even more troubles!

Answer (score 2):

The possible reason for this to happen is you might have installed the plugin in a wrong way or the destination of the file might have changed by some means.
Make sure these 2 are correct on the 1st place.

If you are confident about these 2 are proper. Make sure the actual SDK_Manager.exe runs directly from its folder destination if double clicked.

which will be present in your android SDK path--->\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe

Comment: I checked the points you mentioned.The problem isnt solved. The same problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Open android.bat in sdk/tools folder by right click on it and click edit

find the line-

```
set java_exe=
```

edit it to your path to java.exe like

```
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
```

then delete the next line which is

```
call lib\find_java.bat
```

This one worked for me......

Check out [this](http://techathlon.com/fix-android-sdk-manager-failing-open-android-development-tools-bundle/) link......

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of frustration not getting solution to launch SDK Manager manually and in Eclipse. Finally, I figured out the solution and whatever solution available elsewhere is not correct on recent development. Thought of adding this info of Android SDK for new to mobile testing enthusiast:

1. Android encourages users to use Android IDE, so you don't find Android ADT bundle zip file in the site. You may need to download from untrusted source if you want to configure SDK to Eclipse manually.

Solution:

1. Download JDK, install it, set environment variables for JDK and JRE in your system. (if not sure, please see videos of how to install JDK)
2. Download Eclipse, unzip it and launch Eclipse
3. In Eclipse, Go to Windows and click Install new software
4. Enter this url in work-with:  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/  and press Enter
5. Select Developer Tools checkbox and click Next and finish
6. Click Ok for permission in popup
7. Click OK to restart Eclipse
8. Click Cancel in setting SDK in preferences
9. Parallely, Android Installation Tool windows opens up, click next
10. Select automatically downloading Android SDK tools and api versions
11. It downloads all required tool, it restarts the eclipse, sets preferences,

Now you can launch SDK Manager from Eclipse or go to SDK tools folder and launch Android in tools folder.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this is using newer version of android sdk tools.
Eclipse supports sdk tools version 25.2.5 and build-tools version 25.0.3. The reason is google has removed some optional/deprecated tools from sdk tools in release 25.3.0. But eclipse needs them to work with android projects. So the thing you can do is delete tools folder from your sdk and download eclipse supported version

Android SDK Tools:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip

Extract them in your sdk installation directory.

You can now access to SDK manager by using the `android` command, which is located in tools directory of your sdk.  You can also do this from eclipse.
Note that Eclipse supports build-tools version 25.0.3 and older, so you will have to download them. For other tools you can select latest version. They are supported by eclipse.